# Loading a page when logging in and only when logging in

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a login page that when you login in successfully you will be redirected to a page called `gallery.html`.  However, when you type in the url with /gallery.html it will take you to the page that im trying to secure with logging in.  What's the best way to use a conditional statement to prevent the page from being opened by typing in the exact URL? like a check before the page starts to load,

Answer (score 3):

Simple, Use `session` variable on log-in, redirect the user to `gallery.html` if the session id is set, otherwise redirect to login page, something like this

```
if($_SESSION['userid']){
  header( 'Location: gallery.html' ) ;
  exit();
}elseif($_SESSION['userid'] == ''){
  header( 'Location: login.html' ) ;
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Something like this can be handy to put in an include file that can be easily included on any pages you need to make visible only to authenticated users.

Comment: thank you for the great answers. Thats what I was thinking but wasnt sure if there was another way. appreciate the advice

Answer (score 2):

I like to create a function to handle this kind of thing:

```
function loggedin() {
    if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or something shorter using a ternary operator:

```
function loggedin() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}
```

Now to make the check, simply call the function within an if statement:

```
if ( loggedin() ) {
    // only logged in users can see this
}
```

OR

```
if ( !logged_in() ) {
    // only users who aren't looged in can see this
}
```

Much easier than typing something like `if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {` every time!

Comment: i like this way of doing the check. much nicer especially lest typing

Answer (score 1):

if you want to not show gallery.html to anonymous user, use this code at top of page

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_user_login_id']))
{
    //redirect to home page
}
```

this code will prevent from anonymous user to view this page.

Answer (score 1):

Use $_SESSION variable in gallery.php to check if the $_SESSION is set.

Although, I believe you will have to change the file name from gallery.html to gallery.php

```
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['secret_variable'])
    {
        echo "<br/>Error Message<br/>";
        return;
    }
    ?>
```

Continue with the rest of the code. If the user access the gallery.php by specifying the URL, he/she will end up with `Error Message`.

The `$_SESSION['secret_variable']` should be set after you figure out that the user has a valid username and password to ensure a valid login.

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your login status in sessions and check for the session in your to-be-secured pages.

```
  <?php 
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['login_status'])) {
              // Add permission denied message or redirect back to the login page
         }

   ?>
```

However, this can be done in PHP pages, not in a page with .html extenstion (unless you have explicitly specified your web server configuration with an "AddType x-httpd-php .html" directive.)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is using php. Save your gallery.html as gallery.php or enter below code on top of the gallery.html page before all the coding. Then use a SESSION variable ($_SESSION['userID'] in here) to store current login details.

`<?php`
`if(! isset($_SESSION['userID'])){  //userID or something to identify the user`
`header('Location:login.php');   //redirects to the login page`
`}else{`
 `header('Location:gallery.php');   //redirect to the gallery.php for valid login`
`}`
`?>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of preventing someone from typing in the URL and requesting the page.  THe only thing you'll be able to do is check if they are logged in on the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the cookie or session once the user is logging in. so you will set the session or cookie for the user. Every time while entering that particular url you have to check the session for showing that page or else redirect to the login page